# STL performance in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, stl

I really like STL because of its simple syntax and its flexibility. Sometimes usage of STL is a must because Foundation array and dictionary cannot contain non-object. So, what I want to know are:

- Is there any performance penalty of STL in iOS ?
- Has anyone compared the performance between STL containers and the corresponding Foundation classes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

STL should work well on iOS, and normally it will be substantially faster than Foundation classes.